# MySQL Syntax for Date Search in a Text Input Field

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I want to let users search for a birthdate in a database. However, instead of having separate fields for MM, DD, YYYY, I want them to be able to type it as a string, then I use the STR_TO_DATE function in MySQL to look up the birthdates and return a list of people with that birthday.

Since the input is just a text field, there can be multiple options entered. For example here are some of the types of ways people will type in the search:

```
Search MM-DD-YYYY: 
Option 1: 09-22-1958
Option 2: 09/22/1958
Option 3: 9/22/1958
Option 4: 9/22/58
```

The 4th option, 9/22/58, is returning correct results in some cases but not in others. Sometimes, it says no results.. but other times with that same format but a different date, the results will come... even though the dates are all in the database correctly. I think this has to do with there not being a trailing '0' in front of the month of 9, combined with no "19" in front of the year of "58".

However, I can't seem to figure out how to make the query search be able to look up all options. Also, it works in some cases, like 8/31/83.. but not in other cases like 9/22/58.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM database 
      WHERE 
      Birth_Date=STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('$search', '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y') or 
      Birth_Date=STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('$search', '-', '/'), '%m/%d/%Y')"
```

It seems that I am missing something here. I have added the STR_TO_DATE function, the REPLACE function to take care of the / and - ... but, what else do I need to have to make sure that it would work in the case of 9/22/58 and other cases?

Comment: better transform the date in the application and then send an ISO datestring to mysql.

Comment: the problem is that the user can also search by other fields such as name, address, etc.. all in the same input field. I suppose I can make another field separate, but hoping I can find a solution to use just one search box.

Comment: imo this conversion in the database is a really bad idea and uncessary. you could also test for a valid date-string in application and react accordingly.

Comment: I would do all the string conversion stuff client side, in application code.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be, first convert the date in proper format via php then query the result.

```
$date = "9/22/58"; //user input

$search = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: but the input field also accepts other information, such as name, address, etc.. so not sure this would work.

Comment: You can check entered text is valid date, is yes then you append Birth_Date checking in where clause.